# XSLT display data in repeated columns

Tags: xslt

I need to create XSLT to show results in repeated columns to avoid scrolling in the page.

While checking for a solution i found an example from W3schools - 
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

The above example shows how to add multiple columns using XSLT. But my requirement is different. If we take the same example, i want data to be displayed as below

**Title          Author    Title       Author**

A-Title      Gregory    D-Title      Ford

B-Title      Dr.John     E-Title      Sean

C-Title      Bellucci     F-Title      Steven


To avoid scrolling for the Users I need to split the data in two columns. Also the results need to be sorted vertically in alphabetical order.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
John

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an example of the XML you're starting from and any XSLT you've tried so far?  Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0 only?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h1>Collection</h1>
    <table border="1" style="display:inline-block">
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:variable name="sorted-cds">
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
          <xsl:sort select="title" order="ascending" data-type="text" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="n" select="ceiling(count(catalog/cd) div 2)"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($sorted-cds)/cd[position() &lt;= $n]">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::cd[$n]/title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::cd[$n]/artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The basic idea is to sort the CDs as node set (`sorted-cds`)
calculate the half of number of rows (`n`) and and then iterate over 
the first half of the collection (`position() <= $n`).
In order to get the corresponding second CD in the same row, just
skip (`following-sibling::`) `$n` CDs in the collection.

(Note that you need to include the common EXSL extensions `xmlns:exsl...`
because the non-standard `exsl:node-set` function is used.)

Another note: If you want to try out the above in the page 
you linked in your question, you may need to replace the `&lt;=`
by `&amp;lt;=`; they seem to have a quoting bug there(?).